# Android Camera Application: Outputting bitmap to second activity

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, camera

I want to save the image internally, then display it in the next Activity. Here is the camera activity (the preview and everything works perfectly, but when I press the Capture button I get sent to the second activity but it's just a white screen...no bitmap image is displayed).

Main Camera Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContext = this;

    if(checkCameraHardware(mContext)){
        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        // Add a listener to the Capture button
        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // get an image from the camera
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}

private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("img.jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fos.write(data);
                    fos.close();
                     return "img.jpg";
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if(result != null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,     ImageDisplayActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(ImageDisplayActivity.KEY_PATH,   "img.jpg");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        }.execute();


    }
};
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if  (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA))    {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
/** Create a File for saving an image or video */


}
```

Here is the second, Display Image activity:

```
public class ImageDisplayActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static final String KEY_PATH = "img.jpg";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_FILE");

       try {
           java.io.FileInputStream in = this.openFileInput(path);
           Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
           ImageView mImg;
           mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_displayer);
           mImg.setRotation(90);
           mImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           in.close();

       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }




}


private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    Bitmap b = null;
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
        fis.close();
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return b;
}

}
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
02-26 00:56:05.905  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException

02-26 00:56:05.905  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:2456)

02-26 00:56:05.905  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:1072)

02-26 00:56:05.905  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:180)

02-26 00:56:05.905  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at com.commonsware.android.test1.ImageDisplayActivity.onCreate(ImageDisplayActivity.java:33)

02-26 00:56:05.915  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)

02-26 00:56:05.915  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)

02-26 00:56:05.915  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)

02-26 00:56:05.915  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)

02-26 00:56:05.915  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)

02-26 00:56:05.915  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)

02-26 00:56:05.925  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

02-26 00:56:05.925  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

02-26 00:56:05.925  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)

02-26 00:56:05.925  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

02-26 00:56:05.925  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)    
02-26 00:56:05.925  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187) 
02-26 00:56:05.925  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
02-26 00:56:05.925  12138-12138/com.commonsware.android.test1 W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ImageDisplayActivity.KEY_PATH` as `key` instead of `EXTRA_FILE` to get value which is passed from previous Activity with Intent :

```
String path = getIntent().getStringExtra(ImageDisplayActivity.KEY_PATH);
```

Comment: I changed this exactly how you said but I'm still not seeing the bitmap image on the second activity.

Comment: @nnnnnnitters: where calling `setContentView` in second Activity?

Comment: I called setContentView and that seems to have fixed it! But the image that is displayed is not the same dimensions and the camera preview...It is displayed smaller and in the middle of the screen but I want it to be the original size. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @nnnnnnitters: why not calling `decodeFile` method try to set BitmapFactory.Options after reading Bitmap from file